# DynamoDB query returning nil every time even when the object exists

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a query that returns nil each time I run it despite there being items with the key I pass.

I set my expression to the following:

```
queryExpression.keyConditionExpression = "#uID = :uidValue"

// in my model class
var uID: String?
```

uidValue is the value I'm comparing "uID" to.

I've read through AWS's documentation on this and haven't found anything that's helped.

```
//implementation of query
let dynamoDbObjectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.default()


dynamoDbObjectMapper.query(GameTracker.self, expression: queryExpression) { (output: AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput?, error: Error?) in
  if(output == nil){
    //create new user here, this keeps getting run each time
  }else{
    //user found, run other logic
  }
}
```

I'm running uID's that I know exist in my table, but it keeps returning nil each time and throwing an error.  Unfortunately, AWS docs on this don't offer many new insights into what might be going wrong from what I've found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by assigning uID as my partition key and just searching by hashkey instead.